# Java: change "VK_UP" to KeyEvent.VK_UP

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap, keyevent

I need to change/parse text like `"VK_UP"` (or simply `"UP"`) to the `KeyEvent.VK_UP` constant in Java. I dont want to use the number `38` instead since it will be saved in a `.txt` config file so anybody could rewrite it.

Best solution would be to have this hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> keyConstant;
```

Where key would be the name (`"VK_UP"`) and value would be key code (`38`).

Now the question is: How can I get this map without spending all evening creating it manually?

Comment: Reflection? [docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.java.html](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.java.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection.

Something among the lines of the following should work, sans exception handling:

```
public static int parseKeycode(String keycode) {
    // We assume keycode is in the format VK_{KEY}
    Class keys = KeyEvent.class; // This is where all the keys are stored.
    Field key = keys.getDeclaredField(keycode); // Get the field by name.
    int keycode = key.get(null); // The VK_{KEY} fields are static, so we pass 'null' as the reflection accessor's instance.
    return keycode;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a simple one-liner:

```
KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredField(keycode).get(null);
```